# WebdriverIO & Java - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException in IFrame

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm facing an exception (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException) when I try to get element "email". Since I just started playing with WebDriver I'm probably missing some important concept about those race conditions.

```java
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
login.click();
WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.id("iFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
email.sendKeys(USERNAME);
```

Few things that I've tried but with no success:

Set an implicitly wait:

```java
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Create a WebDriverWait:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
login.click();
WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.id("iFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
WebElement email = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("email"))); 
// and WebElement email = wait.until(visibilityOf(By.id("email"))); 
email.sendKeys(USERNAME);
```

Create a FluentWait:

```java
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
login.click();
WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.id("iFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
        .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
        .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement email = wait.until(d ->
        d.findElement(By.id("email")));
email.sendKeys(USERNAME);
```

The only way I managed to make it work was using the old and good Thread.sleep() (ugly as well)

```java
WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.id("login"));
login.click();
WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.id("iFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
email.sendKeys(USERNAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the **email** element as the the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()`.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `elementToBeClickable()`.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("iFrame")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("email"))).sendKeys(USERNAME);
  ```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: I got exactely behavior executing your code. If I put a sleep, or delay the execution in debug mode, between line 2 and 3 it works :(

Comment: @VeryNiceArgumentException Can you share the relevant HTML please?

Comment: this is the site: www.globo.com When you click on login (image at top right) it will pop up the iframe I want to read from. Ids are differemt from the code I posted, but you can see HTML at least.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code is ok, but [Chrome driver 78 linux 64](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/78.0.3904.105/chromedriver_linux64.zip) bits is messed up. I've tried with Firefox (geckodriver-0.26.0) and it worked like a charm.

Thanks for the help @DebanjanB